# HTML message won't render correctly with mailcore2 api when message contain inline attachment

Tags: ios, mailcore2

I have a message on server that contain only inline images. In message they are represented as array of parts(htmlInlineAttachments). And when I render message with **htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage:folder:** method it returns html without any image. What I need to do to render html correctly?

Comment: See examples in the repository.

Comment: did not find solution yet